# weakly-referenced object no longer exists while CPU is over utilized

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script that over utilize the CPU, causing it to reach 100% usage.
My question is, can CPU over-utilization cause an class object or locally defined objects to be deleted or not be defined in the first place, causing this error:

```
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Note that i have tested and this error is clearly happening when the CPU is over utilized, i am just trying to analyze and understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, high CPU utilization does not have any such effect. Your code has a bug.